# Overstaying in Norway?

Tags: schengen, norway, health, overstay

My case is my visa will expire on Dec 23 2015. I got pregnant and my due date is january 9 2016. I am already 34 weeks in my pregnancy. Can I still travel by plane for 20 hours to get home to my home country from here in norway? If not then it is possible I will be overstaying until I give birth. How much is the fine for this? Will I get deported? And how long is the ban from Norway? Or I am also be banned in the rest of the shengen countries for overstaying here in norway? I hope somebody could answer.

Comment: Is it a Schengen visa or something else? When did you enter Norway? Sorry for the intrusive question, but were you pregnant when you entered? A Norwegian site implies that if you knew about a possible issue, then you should have planned for it--aka leaving when you were still able to safely travel.

Comment: Some airlines won't let you travel in your ninth month; others in your third trimester (maybe with a dr's note). You'd have to look at flights, and check the individual airline policies. If you do fly, you might try to get a long transit where you can take a break, put your feet up, etc.

Comment: You should edit your question with this additional information

Comment: Apparently you can renew your aupair permit if you've held it for less than 2 years: http://www.udi.no/en/want-to-renew/au-pair/  Unfortunately, if you wanted to do that, you ought to have done it last week -- at least a month before expiration of the existing permit.

Comment: Contact UDI. I am sure you can get an extension for medical reasons.

Comment: Is the father a Norwegian citizen? If so, the child will become Norwegian citizenship at birth and you will as the child's mother be entitled to stay in Norway. Legally, there is no foundation for your stay in Norway after December 23rd and before the child is born, but I would assume that you can find a solution with UDI, so that you are not required to leave Norway shortly before birth.

Comment: Surely you can travel by land, to Denmark, Sweden, Finland?

Comment: @MarkMayo Can you expand on your comment? Home country is 20 hrs by air away. She's on an au pair visa, so wouldn't she need to get another visa for one of those countries? And within a week? I don't think you made a constructive comment.

Comment: @mkennedy it was merely a rushed suggestion - if they're worried about getting expelled from the country, but can't fly (pregnant), one option might be to get a fast visa for those countries, bus across, and sort out a returning visa from there.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the child has now been born in Norway, you no longer have a problem. For the benefit of others, I will answer as if it is still December 2015 and your visa has not yet expired.

If you have missed the chance to renew your visa, and you cannot renew it by briefly leaving the country (which in this case of course you couldn't), then it is **generally optimal to overstay and to ask for assistance from the immigration authority**. This is especially true with your extenuating circumstance of 9th month of pregnancy -- it is medically risky to travel by air transport.

I overstayed a visa once and didn't notice until I was out of my host country on a business trip -- and what happened to me is that I became homeless until my employer procured a new work permit for me. Trust me, that sucked. If I had simply stayed put, there would have been multiple options open to be to reapply from within the host country.

Disclaimer: Except for sharing my personal experience, I am not qualified to provide immigration advice. I am also not qualified to provide medical advice.